# How to iterate over full list in python? For loop stops at 1st instance

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I have been trying to get my for loop to iterate over the full values of the list named pdg_vals. I want to get the index number of all values that are 14. I then want to create a new list using these index values.

Python keeps returning the first instance of the stipulation. That is, it shows that the new list I am appending (pdg_ent) is filled with only the index value of the first instance where pdg_vals has value 14.

I tried appending using the += operation.

here is the code:

```
myfile = ROOT.TFile("/home/hilary/root/compile/Research/GENIE_atm.root")
mydir = myfile.GENIE
mytree = mydir.Get("Event")
pdg_vals = [] #an empyt list to fill pdg values
for e in mytree:
    for v in e.mc_pdg:
        pdg_vals += [v] #fill empty list with mc_pdg values
#pdg_vals
pdg_ent = []

for x in pdg_vals:
    if x == 14:
        pdg_ent += [pdg_vals.index(x)]

pdg_ent
```

here is what the pdg_vals list looks like:

```
[12,
 1000180400,
 2112,
 1000180390,
 11,
 2212,
 2212,
 2000000002,
 2000000101,
 14,
 1000180400,
 2212,
 1000170390,
 14,
 2214,
 2212,
 111,
 2212,
 111,
 2212,
 2000000002,
 12,
 ...]
```

clearly if I correctly write my code, the first value in my new pdg_ent list should be 9 and the second should be 13 etc...

here is the output of the pdg_ent

```
[9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 9,
 ...]
```

why is python appending the new list with just the first instance of the value 14 from the old list?

Answer (score 0):

### The 'index' function is not what you want

pdg_vals.index(x) will, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) states, "Return zero-based index in the list of the **first** item whose value is equal to x" - which in your case is 9 whenever x is 14. So if you don't want the first value returned, that's not what you need.

### enumerate

The enumerate function (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) seems to be what you require:

```
for index, value in enumerate(list):
  if value == 14:
     print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
for x in pdg_vals :
    if x == 14 :
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

This will work for your specific scenario. HOWEVER, if you need it sorted in ascending order, your search will be much faster with a binary search.